# dyld: Library not loaded: when installing on actual iPhone

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods

I am having an error with the pods 'Parse' and 'Bolts' when building the app on a device. It works great on the simulator though. The error is the following:
`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts` followed by `Reason: no suitable image found.`

The device is an iPhone XS Max running iOS 13.3.1. I tried fixing it by adding `#use_modular_headers!` in the pod file, but that creates a new set of problems with other pods.

Comment: Please share your pod file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to Apple not allowing free developer account installs on iOS 13.3.1. Updating to iOS 13.5 fixed the problem.